# How can I get the pre-sort index of a record in an ExtJS store?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

When I load JSON data into an ExtJS store, the index of each record reflects the original order of the objects in the array. However, after applying a sort to the store, the index changes based on the new order.

How can I access the original index as it was when the data was loaded? I need this to perform crud operations on the records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like FoxMulder900 said, you can add an id to the record itself to have the original index position, but if you don't want or can't change your source, you can add an idGenerator to your model like this:

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        // your fields here
    ],
    idgen: {
        type: 'sequential',
        id: 'myIdField',
        seed: 0
    }

});
```

So when you call `record.get('myIdField')` you will always get your original index.

I've setup a fiddle demonstrating this: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/cgd (Double click any record to check the Original index and new index).

Comment: Very nice! I didn't know about the sequential idgen, very very useful.

Comment: It works even better on ExtJS 5: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-identifier

Answer (score 1):

That information might be lost once you have sorted the store (not entirely sure). I would just try to include an id in the record itself. The initial index should work as the id if you can include that in the JSON before you send it.